# Wireless is disabled after reboot, suspend, hibernate in 12.04

Tags: wireless

I have Ubuntu 12.04 in my laptop (Samsung Q330). After some time I got a problem. Wireless connection always disabled after reboot, suspend or hibernate. I have to swith it on each time. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try command

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

If you want this code to run every time when your system boots up, paste this command in the file

```
/etc/rc.local
```

and save it.